# PHP cUrl returning empty string without var_dump

Tags: php, curl, screen-scraping, var-dump

I was using cUrl to scrape prices for some products . All worked well,a few months, until now .

Now after cURL, I get an empty result .. apparently ... because if I do a var_dump on the returned variable, it works ... and I don't understand how can a var be empty until i print it ?!

This is my full cURL functions :

```
function linkcurl($targetURL){

$linkcurl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($linkcurl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookie.tmpz");
curl_setopt($linkcurl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookie.tmpz");
curl_setopt($linkcurl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
//curl_setopt($linkcurl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, random_user_agent());
curl_setopt($linkcurl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($linkcurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);   

curl_setopt($linkcurl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);

curl_setopt($linkcurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // debug headers sent - 1
curl_setopt($linkcurl, CURLOPT_URL, $targetURL);

$datax = curl_exec ($linkcurl);

curl_close($linkcurl);

return $datax;
}

$prdhtml = linkcurl($product_page_url); //
```

No, i did try to add more options to my cURL butit does not change a thing :

```
curl_setopt($linkcurl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($linkcurl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($linkcurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($linkcurl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
```

Same result, nothing changed .

I did try to add a var_dump ob_start to my curl function like this :

```
ob_start();
return curl_exec ($ch);
ob_end_clean();
```

Still nothing .

I also tried to capture the cURL output outside the function like this :

```
ob_start();
var_dump($prdhtml);
$prdhtml = ob_get_clean();
```

Still .. nothing changed ... I also tried varionts with print_r and var_export... nothing .

I also did try a fixed user agent for cURL and also random user agents .. nothing...

The only time it works (from time to time,not always) is if I do a simple var_dump($prdhtml); of the string as a result on page, and I don't get how that is different from ob_start .

I don't understand what the problem is and how to fix it ...

EDIT:

sample code and fiddle :
http://codepad.viper-7.com/aePjg7

Comment: Output buffering is unrelated to `curl`. You seem to be using output buffering incorrectly.

Comment: so where is your complete fragment of code?? what variable and where are you trying to use? in your question I see only `var_dump($prdhtml);` but there is no `$prdhtml` initialization before. so what are you talking about?

Comment: could you provide us the url `$targeturl` for test request?

Comment: and as I stated above .... the scripts worked great for about 5 months but now something change on the website ( server ) I was scrapping ...nothing changed in the code .

Comment: yes Kim, but I don't see how that is relevant ... there must be a problem that other people also encountered and fixed .. anyway a sample link is this (i added the spaces in the link, not a mistake) :
http: // www . v-tac .ro/lampi-led-de-gradina/corp-iluminat-led-ingropat-gu10-230v-detalii

Comment: I also did try different IP addresses if someone thinks it's a connection problem, as I have access to multiple connections .... it's not that .

Comment: so it could help, if you tried my code it return "string(36) "Could not resolve host: www.v-tac.ro""... oh no, sorry, that works for me from another server. so, try my code from answer - that works fine for me with your provided url

Comment: It does work 2 out of 5 .. and I did try to add a sleep time of even 20 secs ... same result . and thanks for you code, but I have the result . nothing changed .

Answer (score 0):

```
function linkcurl($targetURL){

$linkcurl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($linkcurl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookie.tmpz");
curl_setopt($linkcurl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookie.tmpz");
curl_setopt($linkcurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);   
curl_setopt($linkcurl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');   
curl_setopt($linkcurl, CURLOPT_URL, $targetURL);

$datax = curl_exec ($linkcurl);
 if ($datax) {
curl_close($linkcurl);

return $datax;
} else {
return curl_error ( $linkcurl );
}
}

$prdhtml = linkcurl($product_page_url); //
```

Comment: you have an error here :return curl_error ( $linkurl ); .. it's linkcurl .

Tried it .. same results . nothing changed . and no, I don't get a curl error .

Comment: look, this code works fine for me, but you said it doesn't work for you. the only difference I see is the `$product_page_url = "http://www.v-tac.ro/lampi-led-de-gradina/corp-iluminat-led-ingropat-gu10-230v-detalii";` that I have right before the last line `$prdhtml = linkcurl($product_page_url);`. Are you sure that you use the same url?

Comment: if you don't have curl error do `var_dump($datax);` right after your cal `$datax = curl_exec ($linkcurl);`

Comment: If you want, I can give you an array with 100 links from that page .. that is not the problem ... I'm sticking to my initial fix ... if I do a simple var_dump of the result it works .. if not, it crashes with an blank result ... and the result is not blank ... most weird !

Comment: you added the second comment at the same time with me .. that was my initial fix .. kinda ... if I don't do a simple var_dump it's like the result is empty .. but I don;t have a curl error, and if I print / dump the result ... it's not empty ... very very annoying ...

Comment: it seems you don't provide your real code to us. my separated code works fine, and I guess, for you my code if you put it as separate file works fine either. so if you need help, you should provide your real code, I can help in that case, if not - that is up to you to figure out what did you do differently.

Comment: i think you are trying to find the answer in the wrong place ... it is the right code .. you don't seem to understand that it does crash after a second or third try .. or totally random .

Comment: further more ... I could work with the simple var_dump solution as it works when I do that .. but after 10-12 links and 10-12 var dump on the page, the browser tends to crash ...

Comment: it doesn't matter where I try to find the problem or solution, but I can't reproduce your bug. so until you can provide a good example of code+environment settings that reproduce your bug nobody can help you :-)

Comment: Oh yeah ?! try this then :

http://codepad.viper-7.com/3omC7H

and tell me ... does that work for you man ?

Comment: your link gave me this response, check as new Answer. So I don't know what do you want to say by this, but the only thing I see - it works, even it is not exactly the same as my code. and there are so many timeouts...

Comment: dude ... if you look at the result, you will see : trying to get property of non-object  AKA the result is empty . now if you see, there is a var_dump commented out . take comment out and see how it works ... THAT IS MY PROBLEM !